# Subtract 2 fields in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

My query looks like this so far...

```
{
    where: {
      id: event.pathParameters.picId
    },
    'include': [{
      'model': db.reputations,
      'where': {
        'type': 'V_UP'
      },
      'as': 'up_reputations',
      'required': false
    }, {
      'model': db.reputations,
      'where': {
        'type': 'V_DONW'
      },
      'as': 'down_reputations',
      'required': false
    }],
    'attributes': [
      'id',
      'title',
      'data',
      'createdAt',
      [db.Sequelize.fn('count', db.Sequelize.col('up_reputations.type')), 'upVotes'],
      [db.Sequelize.fn('count', db.Sequelize.col('down_reputations.type')), 'downVotes']
    ]
}
```

What I need is one last attribute, `score`, to be `upVotes` - `downVotes` but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
'attributes': [
      'id',
      'title',
      'data',
      'createdAt',
      [db.Sequelize.fn('count', db.Sequelize.col('up_reputations.type')), 'upVotes'],
      [db.Sequelize.fn('count', db.Sequelize.col('down_reputations.type')), 'downVotes'],
      [db.Sequelize.literal('(upVotes - downVotes)'), 'score']
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[db.Sequelize.literal('COUNT(`up_reputations.type`) - COUNT(`down_reputations.type`)'), 'score']
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22065512)